# Empty DataFrame : Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask

I have written a code using python , selenium and flask but I don't know why in the "results" variable, I am getting an empty variable.

Could anyone help me please ?

Thank you !

https://pastebin.fr/131484

I have tried many ways but nothing

Comment: Please add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and not dump your entire code as link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.